# Adequate Mean Squared Error while using Deep Autoencoder/ Deep Learning in general

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm currently wondering when to stop training of Deep Autoencoders, especially when it seems to be stuck in a local minimum.

Is it essential to get the training criterium (e.g. MSE) to e.g. 0.000001 and force it to perfectly reconstruct the input or is it okay to keep differences (e.g. stop when the MSE is at about 0.5) depending on the dataset used.

I know that a better reconstruction might lead to better classification results afterwards but is there a "rule of thumb" when to stop? I'm especially interested in rules that have no heuristic character like "if the MSE doesn't get smaller in x iterations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to derive a general rule of thumb for this, as generating NN:s/machine learning is a very problem-specific procedure, and generally, [there is no free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem). How to decide what is a "good" training error to terminate at depends on various problem-specific factors, e.g. the noise in the data. Evaluating your NN only with regard to training sets, with the only objective of minimising the MSE, will many times lead to **overfitting**. With only the training error as feedback, you might tune your NN to the noise in the training data (hence the overfitting). One method to avoid this is *holdout validation*. Instead of only training your NN to given data, your divide your data set into a training set, a validation set (and a test set).

- Training sets: Training and feedback to NN, will naturally keep decreasing with longer training (at least down to "OK" MSE values for the specific problem).
- Validation sets: Evaluate your NN w.r.t. to these, but don't give feedback to your NN/genetic algoritm.

Along with the evaluation-feedback of your training sets you should hence also evaluate the validation set, however without giving feedback to your neural network (NN).

Track the decrease in MSE for training as well as validation sets; generally training error will steadily decrease, whereas, at some point, the validation error will reach a minimum and start to increase with further training. Of course, you cannot know during runtime where this minima occurs, so generally one stores the NN with the lowest validation error, and after this has seemingly not been updated in some time (i.e., in error retrospect: we've passed a minima in validation error), the algorithm is terminated.

See e.g. the following article [Neural Network: Train-validate-Test Stopping](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/05/01/train-validate-test-stopping.aspx) for details, as well as [this SE-statistics thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104713/hold-out-validation-vs-k-fold-validation) discussing two different validation methods.

For the training/validation of Deep Autoencoders/Deep Learning, specifically w.r.t. overfitting, I find the article [Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from Overfitting (*)](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf) to be valuable.

(*) By H. Srivistava, G. Hinton, A. Krizhevsky, I. Sutskever, R. Salakhutdinov, University of Toronto.